# dynamically name mongo key field

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to name a mongo key dynamically based on a variable. For instance,

```
MyCollection.update({_id: id}, 
{ 
  $set: 
   {
     getsNamedDynamically: { 
        //stuff
     }...
```

I would like to set the value of `getsNamedDynamically` in a variable to assign a different key name to the field based on some other factors. I've tried doing this, however, mongo takes the value literally (i.e. as a string) and does not bother to find the variable's value in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried this aproach?(dont know if it works)

```
var dataToSet={};
dataToSet['field']= "some computed value";
```

and then

```
MyCollection.update({_id: id}, 
{ 
  $set: dataToSet
}
```

Comment: Cant believe I didn't think of this. Nice look.

Answer (score 1):

You can set it dynamically, if you are using node v4, you can use the ES6 enhanced literal syntax:

```
MyCollection.update({_id: id}, 
{ 
  $set: {[key] : value}
}
```